# IndexOutOfBoundsException When unzipping an ear file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, ant, indexoutofboundsexception

This is one of the target in my deployment script and it tries to unzip an `.ear` file. It fails with IndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
<target name="unzip">
        <unzip src="${project-name}.ear" dest="${unzip-destination}" />
</target>
```

How do I figure out what is causing this exception? What list/array is this accessing that causes this exception?

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:144)
        at IdentifyServer.modifyZipContents(IdentifyServer.java:215)
        at IdentifyServer.execute(IdentifyServer.java:135)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:758)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
```

Comment: Are you sure the stack trace belongs to your build file snippet?  I don't see Ant's `Expand` class which implements `<unzip>`.  And `IdentifyServer` is not a class Ant would use when running any built-in task.

Comment: @StefanBodewig That's the stacktrace that gets printed on the unix terminal when I run the deployment script

Comment: Quite possible @Nero but either your `<unzip>` is not Ant's built-in task, or the deployment script fails in a different task.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a corrupt ear file. I would suggest creating another zip file and try your ant ask on that zip file. Once you confirm that it works then you know your ant task is working. Then I would focus on looking at how the ear file is being generated.